# how to set the 2nd tab view to appear first when i run the program

Tags: ios

I have a tab view controller with 3 tabs, set it as the 'is Initial View Controller'.
The first tab was the default tab view that is seen when I run the program.

Is there a way to make the second tab to appear first?

Answer (score 0):

```
[theTabBar setSelectedItem:yourViewController];
```

See the [UITabBar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: sorry but where to put this code? i am new to iOS dev. thanks